# from the last 2 days my mvc project is throwing this error when i debug it more than twice after restart ..

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using vs2012 to develop an mvc 4 project.It used to be normal before but from the last 2 days it is trowing this error when i debug it more than twice after restart ...

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)**

I don't have sql server management studio installed on my system which i thought would be a probable reason for this and i am using a sql db which i created using vs .. Can anyone help me out!!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx) its free for download, better than LocalDb (VS2012)

or

open your Server Explorer tab in vs2012, refresh the Data Connection. your LocalDb locked by another modul in your code.